# Llenar un array con objetos de otras clases

Tags: java, array

Necesito un método de nombre "presentarBanda" que va a recibir un objeto del tipo Banda con 5 músicos e imprimir un mensaje. ¿Cómo puedo llenar un array con objetos de otras clases, y usarlo como método?

Mi código es el sigueinte.

```
package presentarbanda;

public class PresentarBanda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //AQUI IRIA EL METODO    
    }

Estas son mis clases.

    package presentarbanda;

/**
 *
 * @author ricar
 */
public class Instrumento {

    //ATRIBUTOS
    private String NombreInstrumento;
    private String TipoInstrumento;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Instrumento (String NombreInstrumento, String TipoInstrumento)
    {
        this.NombreInstrumento = NombreInstrumento;
        this.TipoInstrumento = TipoInstrumento;
    }

    public String getNombreInstrumento()
    {
        return NombreInstrumento;
    }

    public void setNombreInstrumento (String NombreInstrumento)
    {
        this.NombreInstrumento = NombreInstrumento;
    }

    public String getTipoInstrumento()
    {
        return TipoInstrumento;
    }

    public void setTipoInstrumento(String TipoInstrumento)
    {
        this.TipoInstrumento = TipoInstrumento;
    }


}

    package presentarbanda;

/**
 *
 * @author ricar
 */
public class Musico {

    //ATRIBUTOS
    private String NombreMusico;
    private String PosicionMusico;
    private Instrumento instrumento;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Musico (String NombreMusico, String PosicionMusico, Instrumento instrumento)
    {
        this.NombreMusico = NombreMusico;
        this.PosicionMusico = PosicionMusico;
        this.instrumento = instrumento;
    }

    public String getNombreMusico ()
    {
        return NombreMusico;
    }

    public void setNombreMusico(String NombreMusico)
    {
        this.NombreMusico = NombreMusico;
    }

    public String getPosicionMusico()
    {
        return PosicionMusico;
    }

    public void setPosiconMusico(String PosiconMusico)
    {
        this.PosicionMusico = PosicionMusico;
    }

    public Instrumento getInstrumento ()
    {
        return instrumento;
    }

    public void setInstrumento (Instrumento instrumento){
        this.instrumento = instrumento;
    }


}

    package presentarbanda;

/**
 *
 * @author ricar
 */
public class Banda {

    Musico musico[] = new Musico[5];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

También se puede realizar creando la clase banda:

```
public class Banda {

    private Musico[] band = new Musico[5];

    public Banda(Musico[] musicos) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            band[i] = musicos[i];
        }
    }

    public Musico[] getBand() {
        return band;

    }
    public void setBand(Musico[] band) {
        this.band = band;
    }


}
```

Y luego en PresentarBanda mostrar sus integrantes:

```
public class PresentarBanda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instrumento i = new Instrumento("trompeta", "viento");
        Instrumento i2 = new Instrumento("Guitarra", "Cuerdas");
        Musico m = new Musico("erick", "jefe", i);
        Musico m2 = new Musico("erick2", "jefe", i2);
        Musico m3 = new Musico("erick3", "jefe", i);
        Musico m4 = new Musico("erick4", "jefe", i2);
        Musico m5 = new Musico("erick5", "jefe", i);

        Banda banda = new Banda(new Musico[] {m,m2,m3,m4,m5})  ;

        presentarBanda(banda);
    }

    private static void presentarBanda(Banda banda) {
        Musico[] musicos = banda.getBand();
        for (int i = 0; i < musicos.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hola soy "+ musicos[i].getNombreMusico() + " y toco: "+  musicos[i].getInstrumento().getNombreInstrumento());

        }
    }

}
```

En el ejemplo dado, la salida es:

```
Hola soy erick y toco: trompeta
Hola soy erick2 y toco: Guitarra
Hola soy erick3 y toco: trompeta
Hola soy erick4 y toco: Guitarra
Hola soy erick5 y toco: trompeta
```

Comment: Una simple mejora para evitar crear un objeto. La transferencia directa entre arrays `band[i] = musicos[i]; `

Comment: @JDev Muchas gracias, he añadido tu mejora a la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @Rcordoval me sirvio mucho tu respuesta me guie como ejemplo y lo implemente de una manera parecida en mi main. Ahora lo que busco es, crear la calse "Validaciones" llamar a mi arreglo y validar si esta completo, eso creo que se hace con el ciclo for que utilizas en tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas más simples quizá y sea esta, sin necesidad de crear la clase Banda, en la misma clase de tu main podrías crear tu método o bueno queda a criterio tuyo de todas maneras, pero la idea sería la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
       Instrumento i = new Instrumento("trompeta", "viento");
       Musico m = new Musico("erick", "jefe", i);

       presentarBanda(m, i);  
}

public static void presentarBanda(Musico musico, Instrumento instrumento){
            musico.setInstrumento(instrumento);
            List<Musico> listaMusicos = new ArrayList<>();
            listaMusicos.add(musico);            

            //Imprimes a tus musicos
            for(Musico m: listaMusico){
                System.out.println(m.getNombreMusico() + " "
                          + m.getInstrumento().getNombreInstrumento());
            }
    }
```

Saludos!!

Comment: Necesito un metodo de nombre "presentarBanda" que va a resivir un objeto del tipo Banda, donde esta el objeto Banda??

Comment: La idea de la respuesta anterior es que no se haga la clase banda, se implementa el método presentar banda en el principal main(), si no hay clase banda lógicamente no hay objeto. Espero entiendas.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, seria mucho pedir si me puedes explicar que es lo que hacen las 3 primeras lineas del metodo: musico.setInstrumento(instrumento);
            List<Musico> listaMusicos = new ArrayList<>();
            listaMusicos.add(musico);

Comment: Hola, entiendo esa parte, lo que pensaba hacer es: Crear la clase banda con el arreglo y jalarlo al main con una instancia como objeto y ocuparlo como se menciono en la otra respuesta.

Comment: Esto solo permite tener un `Musico` pues la lista se reinicializa en cada llamada.